# How to pass values from AJAX and JQuery to PHP in the same file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am current have the following script. I want pass a value from javascript to php by using AJAX. What's wrong with my code?

```
<script type=" text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $.post("index.php",{host:document.referrer},function(data){});  
    });
</script>
<?php
$dataString=$_POST['host'];
echo $dataString;
?>
```

Comment: theres a lot wrong with it. it is not complete

Answer (score 2):

Since the PHP is executed first, you will never see the `echo $dataString` from your AJAX request.  This code will post your request to the server, but you'll never see the result.

Right now here is what is happening:

1. Your web server renders out your page.
2. Your browser posts a request to index.php, and ignores the result

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) you can see this:

```
$.post('index.php', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

The `data` in that function will return what `echo $dataString;` outputs from your script.

Also, your post isn't configured correctly.  You need to put `data:` before `{host:document.referrer}`